# Get post data, Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I want to fetch posted data. But I am using no form. The data is postet by a jquery script with method `post` and I would like to fetch it.

I know how to fetch parameters

```
$id = $this->getRequest ()->getParam ( 'id', null );
```

and form values

```
$message = $form->getValue ( 'message' );
```

however I want to access post data and not parameters or form values. Any ideas?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Here is my solution;)

```
$this->getRequest()->getPost('id', null);
```

Comment: NULL is the default value, no need to specify it.

Comment: Typical ZF2 - found what I was looking for here but not in the ZF2 documentation.. Thanks

Comment: if nothing is passed to getPost, then it will return all the data. It will act like $_POST. Just used it and it worked fine. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: How to have Lazy mode on? like $post= $this->getRequest(); and then anywhere access it like $post->username where username is the $_POST['username'] ?

Answer (score 18):

Actually, this might be more of what you're looking for.

```
$this->getRequest()->getRawBody();
```

https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.request.html

Comment: Is there a way to get them as array(key value pairs).

Comment: @AbdulBasit please expand; I'm not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an other example:

```
$this->getRequest()->getPost()->toArray()
```

Comment: `$this->getRequest()->getPost()` seems to already be an array, and thus calling `toArray()` on it results in an error. This is what I needed though, +1

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$request->getPost('field_name');
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.