# counting data in a multidemensional array

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-framework3

I upload several files with Zend and want to count the $data array to get the filenames.

```
$data = array_merge_recursive(
                    $this->getRequest()->getPost()->toArray(),
                    $this->getRequest()->getFiles()->toArray()
                    );
```

I found this code for counting in another post

```
array_sum(array_map("count", $data))-1;
```

It gives the right amount of pieces and I can get the names, but it also gives a warning:

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
>   implements Countable

I tried to give the other dimensions like:

```
array_sum(array_map("count", $data['fieldname']))-1;
```

But like expected, it doesn't work.

Any help appreciated! The only question is how to get the amount of given filenames.

***edit regarding to the answer I post a screenshot how the $data array looks like, which is correct

[image]

And here what the statement with the warning counts (of course 1 is to subtract). Perhaps there is an other possibility to count.

[image]

So everything might be nice, but I want to get rid of the warning.

Comment: I think getPost() already returns an array, try without. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745865/get-post-data-zend-framework/27988986#27988986

Comment: I'm not a zend person, but would `count($this->getRequest()->getFiles()->toArray())` give you a count of the files?

Comment: @Jules R. no that is not right, I get everything I want properly in this array, but I'm not able to count. The array_summ XX counts also correct but it gives a warning

Comment: @Nigel Ren it gives the result of 1 if I pick 3 files

Comment: @pia-sophie have you tried without ?

Comment: yes I trued with toArray() and without

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the added screenshot of the `$data` array, shouldn't you be doing this the below?

```
count($data['PAD_Document_Path'])
```

Get specific filenames by looping like so

```
foreach($data['PAD_Document_Path'] as $key => $value) {
    $name = pathinfo($value)['filename'];
    // do stuff with name
}
```

See [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php). From that docs page:

> Example #1 pathinfo() Example
>
> ```
> <?php
> $path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');
>
> echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
> echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
> echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
> echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
> ?>
> ```
>
> The above example will output:
>
> ```
> /www/htdocs/inc
> lib.inc.php
> php
> lib.inc
> ```

Comment: $test=count($data['PAD_Document_Path']); works gives the amount of 3 which is ok for my testscenario $countpads =$this->getRequest()->getFiles()->count(); doesn't work, gives the amount of 1

Comment: Alright, thanks for giving that a go. Have removed it from the answer.